# Unable to print Car year in Java

Tags: java, string, object, methods

I have two classes. I am trying to return a string object that says the year a car model was made. I was able to successfully print out the color and max speed of the two objects.

The first thing I did was create a `private int yearMade` variable in the `Car` Class, and the variable in the method below. I then tried to reference the `carYear` variable in the constructor.

The only thing that I think I am missing would be to enter the actual car year in the parameters in the `CarTest` class. But entering a year did not successfully print out the year of the car.

```
public class Car {
   private final String color;
   private int maxSpeed;
   private int yearMade;

   public String carInfo(){
      return color + " Max Speed:" + maxSpeed + yearMade;
   }

   //This is constructor of Car Class
   Car(String carColor, int speedLimit, int carYear){
       this.color = carColor;
       this.maxSpeed = speedLimit;
       this.yearMade = carYear;
    }
}


public class CarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Car maruti = new Car("Red", 160);
        Car ferrari = new Car("Yellow", 200);
        System.out.println(maruti.carInfo());
        System.out.println(ferrari.carInfo());
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you able to create a Car with only two params when your constructor takes 3 params ? That should throw compile error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where did you enter the year? What did it print?

Comment: Change Car maruti = new Car("Red", 160,<provide year here>);
Car ferrari = new Car("Yellow", 200,<provide year here>); otherwise you will not be able to create object.Also year value will not be set.

Comment: well you are trying to print a string + string + int + int, those last two int's will add together first before printing out. do color + " Max Speed:" + maxSpeed + ", Year Made: " + yearMade;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your max speed and car year together before printing. try something like this

```
public String carInfo(){
    return "Color: " + color + ", Max Speed:" + maxSpeed + ", Year Made: " + yearMade;
}
```

Then create the object using your 3 parameter constructor and call the method like so

```
Car ferrari = new Car("Yellow", 200, 1995);//make sure you add in the year
System.out.println(ferrari.carInfo());
```

Comment: Thank you, this was my first question on Stack Overflow. I learned and had a good experience.

Comment: glad you had a good learning experience! feel free to mark as the answer to close the question! good luck with programming and keep asking questions @KevinMyrick